# What if there's no ANSI code page in C#?

Tags: c#, android, encoding, mono, codepages

I'm developing an app with Unity3d.

As you know, we can write code in C# because Unity3d provides the environment using Mono. I don't know it's due to Mono or Unity3d itself but there's a problem with setting ANSI encoding for some languages, such as Chinese, Japanese and Korean. When I run my app **on Android**, all Code pages I need occur error messages like this.

> NotSupportedException: CodePage 50227 not supported

If you read the explanations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx), it says

"**An asterisk in the last column indicates that the code page is natively supported by the .NET Framework, regardless of the underlying platform.**"

The CodePage 50227 is indicated by an asterisk!

I said I'm having a trouble with Android, but it also occurs the exceptions on Windows too. In fact, much better than on Android, because on Windows I can use some ANSI encodings which didn't work but still very limited compared to when writing code with Visual Studio.

**If mono or Unity3d doesn't support ANSI encodings fully, is there anything I can do?**

I really need to read some text files written in ANSI encodings and save them in UTF encoding. Of course, I can create a jar plugin for this job, but I don't want to due to performance reasons. (I'm already using too many jar files in Unity3d) If possible, I want to write in C# or in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The CodePage 50227 is indicated by an asterisk

Sorry, but that's irrelevant. Mono (whether running on Windows or Android) is not "the .NET Framework". It is an attempt at a compatible implementation, but Microsoft's documentation for .NET isn't intended to be a reliable reference for non-Microsoft implementations of the API.

> If mono or Unity3d doesn't support ANSI encodings fully, is there anything I can do?

These encodings should be fully supported by the underlying OS. Unfortunately, if Mono does not itself support them (which should be surprising to me, but I guess it's not really), then you will have to use the platform-specific parts of the API (e.g. p/invoke on Windows).

I doubt adding one more jar plugin for Android would cause a significant performance change.

Personally, I'd go that route. But alternatively, if you know in advance which specific encodings you need, and there aren't too many of them, I suppose you could write your own `Encoding` classes in C# as part of your project to support each one. Not something I'd relish, especially for multi-byte encodings like CP 50227, but you should be able to write a regular C# program to build the data tables you'd need, based on the .NET implementation of the encodings. So the actual manual labor involved can be reasonably minimal.

Comment: Thank you so much :)  Yeah, as you said I don't think just one more jar file would affect performance. What I meant was, thinking of adding just one more jar file finally leaded me to the situation I should consider performance. In the beginning I didn't expect I would have many jar libraries like this, so I decided not to add more Jars if possible.